# Rails Capistrano first deploy error with postgres in migration task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, web-deployment, capistrano3

I'm running:

```
cap production deploy
```

Everything works fine until this step:

```
** Execute deploy:migrating
01:05 deploy:migrating
01 ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake db:migrate
01 == 20160811165131 AddRefColorToProfileModels: migrating =======================
01 -- add_reference(:profile_models, :ayes_color, {:foreign_key=>true, :index=>true})
01 rake aborted!
01 StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
01
01 PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "ayes_colors" does not exist
01 : ALTER TABLE "profile_models" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_d2695831c0"
01 FOREIGN KEY ("ayes_color_id")
01   REFERENCES "ayes_colors" ("id")
01 /home/deployer/apps/cubamodela/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/data…
01 /home/deployer/apps/cubamodela/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/data…
01 /home/deployer/apps/cubamodela/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapte…
...
```

I don't know if this is important but anyway, in this failed migration I made a mistake writing eyes_color (I wrote ayes_color), I wrote later other migration to correct this.

The line in ProfileModel class is:

```
belongs_to :eyes_color, class_name: "Color", foreign_key: "eyes_color_id", optional: true
```

And I have a table colors in a previous migration.

```
class CreateColors < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
 def change
  create_table :colors do |t|
   t.string :name

   t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```

If any other info is needed please tell me.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Update

```
class AddRefColorToProfileModels < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
 def change
  add_reference :profile_models, :ayes_color, foreign_key: true, index: true
 end
end
```

Comment: What is the output of `rake db:migrate:status`

Comment: add your `AddRefColorToProfileModels` migration to your post

Comment: From the log a think is rake exit status: 1

Comment: Did you solve it?